# Lead Table To another table in differnt database

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

For example we have a Database A have one table ' A1 ', and second database B have one table ' B1 '.

A and B are not symmetric (Don't have the same table).
A1 and B1 are symmetric (Have the same columns).

Situation : I want to get rows value in B1, but by access to the table A1.

In a .Net MVC solution, I have an entity framework Model created from ' A ', but I want to use the same model(Created from A) for access to the values in the table B1 in B (A1 and B1 are symmetric).

How ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just change the connection string?

Comment: I can't change the connection string because the two databases not have the same tables, and the first model is already created, so if i change the connection string, the solution will not be working.

Comment: That's the opposite of what was posted in the question `I want to use the same model, but the values are from ' B '`. You should create a different, smaller model with only the entities that are common in both databases

Comment: Please can you read again the post because I changed it.

Comment: you do need another model, because the database structure is different. You can write the OnModelCreating conditionally on the targeted database so the type is mapped to the correct table in both cases.